# rewrite/redirect http:// and http://www to https:// using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to editing htaccess files.  What I want to do is:
rewrite/redirect specific  subdomains eg subdomain1, subdomain2, etc from:

```
https://www.subdomain.example.com
http://www.subdomain.example.com
http://subdomain.example.com
```

To:

```
https://subdomain.example.com
```

I've pieced the below code together from other questions, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and help me fix the code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: To clarify, what you are asking for is an external "redirect", not an internal "rewrite".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To canonicalise ("redirect") only the *specific subdomain* ...

> ```
> https://www.subdomain.example.com
> http://www.subdomain.example.com
> http://subdomain.example.com
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> https://subdomain.example.com
> ```

You would need to do it something like this near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(subdomain\.example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The 3rd condition ensures that it only applies to the specific subdomain.

To make this apply to several subdomains (assuming the no-www is canonical for all subdomains) then you could modify just the 3rd condition to identify the subdomains that it should apply to. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?:subdomain1|subdomain2|subdomain3)\.example\.com) [NC]
```

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

This is along the right lines, but it fails to target HTTPS or the www sub-subdomain. Also, checking `%{HTTPS} !on` and `%{SERVER_PORT} ^80$` are really the same thing.

Comment: Hi Mr White, thanks for your solution. Did the trick.  Special thanks for the explanation.  Apologies for the delayed response I was offline for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This will redirect all subdomains from `http://www` to `https://` .

For the `subdomain.example.com` you can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://subdomain.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```